# Cual es el directorio a la que apunta mi IP 89.117.32.59, esta instalado CyberPanel

Tags: ip, vps, 404

**Necesito saber a que ruta esta apuntando mi ip**

> Hace un tiempo instale cyberpanel en mi VPS pero al intentar acceder a la ip solo me dice 404 y es porque no tiene un archivo index.html pero lo que desconozco es la ruta intente en /var/www/html no funciona, agradeceria su ayuda
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: intente ver los logs `sudo tail -f /usr/local/lsws/logs/access.log` y funciona pero no dice en que directorio esta apuntando mi IP

Comment: también me comentaron que el directorio podría ser `/usr/local/lsws/Example/html` pero no es tampoco